# Appearance of bezeled button

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nspopover

This is probably some "ugly Yosemite" issue. So I have a button which is either enabled or disabled. Inside a normal window it looks ok, so you can distinguish between enabled

[image]

and disabled:

[image]

But if I show the very same button in a popover the difference appears to be not that clear:

[image]
[image]

The right one is disabled, but the background seems to be almost the same. Can there be done anything with it? Any parameter which can be set?

Comment: How are the buttons being created? The bezel looks significantly different in the popover compared to the normal window cases (no stroke vs stroke).

Comment: That's true. The 3-fold are created programmatically. The single trash buttons via IB (I did that for comparison reason). But I wonder what would make the different appearance in being selected or not.